# Looping through mysql result set takes up lots of memory, how can I improve this

Tags: php, mysql

```
echo number_format(memory_get_usage()/1048576, 2).'<br/>';

$sql = "query";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($property = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
        continue;
}

    echo number_format(memory_get_usage()/1048576, 2);
```

Just doing the above uses 15mb of memory (it goes from 7 to 22mb between the two echos). It's a big data set.

I have tried:

```
$property = null;
```

before the continue. And I have also tried

```
mysql_free_result ($result);
```

Without success.

Comment: MySQL is probably using the Memory and not from the script itself. How big is your data set? can you show us your query? can you also show the output of  `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_size';` from your MySQL server?

Comment: The MySQL C API provides a function (`mysql_use_result`) that does not buffer the result set before fetching it. There may be an equivalent in the PHP API. That said, 15 MB is lots of memory? What is this, 1995?

Comment: @AirThomas Thank you. I did a mysql_unbuffered_query and the memory usage goes from 15mb to 0.02mb

Comment: @Hardworker Sounds like a good opportunity for you to self-answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the mysql_unbuffered_query function which doesn't hold the result set in the memory, unlike mysql_query.

Credit to airthomas for suggesting I look for an equivalent to mysql_use_result

Answer (score 0):

This probably has nothing to do with PHP. Rather your mysql DB is caching the results to save itself potential future reads, as it's set up to do:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

At that link there are a couple of options listed for disabling query cache.